# Discord.js Node.js | Can't access a JSON file from an "exported" JS file

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord.js

I am having a problem accessing a JSON file from a JS file.

I'm trying to use `` let userInfos = require(`./data/${userId}/infos.json`) ``, but it doesn't work and it says :

> Error: Cannot find module './data/233145138380013568/infos.json'

But the file does exist...

Here is my code :

```
module.exports = {
  name : 'go',
  description : 'Se déplacer dans un nouveau lieu',
  execute(message, args) {

    message.reply(authorizationLevel(message.author.id));

  },
}

function authorizationLevel(userId) {
  let userInfos = require(`./data/${userId}/infos.json`);
  return userInfos.unlockedPlaces;
}
```

And here is my file system : [my project's file system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjB3x.png)

Does someone know where does this problem may come from ? I can access the file from the main js file (bot.js) but I cannot from this go.js file.

Comment: Just a typo. let userInfos = require(`/data/${userId}/infos.json`) 
Or in case you want to use relative path: let userInfos = require(`../../data/${userId}/infos.json`)

Comment: I still get the same error with ```require(`/data/${userId}/infos.json`)```. And there is no other folders before /data/, the JS file I am writing in is in a different folder than the JSON file.

Comment: Using two dots (..) you exit the folder from the current JS file you are at. Same as if you did `cd ..`

Comment: I doesn't work either, I still have the `Error: Cannot find module '../data/233145138380013568/infos.json'` error

Comment: If you are in /commands/user using `..` once will lead you to /commands. Use `..` again and you will be in the `/` folder

Comment: @AwSnap already mentioned `require(\`../../data/${userId}/infos.json\`)`. Have you checked that? Because the error message is not for this one.

Comment: oh ok I though `..` was meant to be replaced by directory names, my bad, I'll try this in 2mn

Comment: @Stereo924 this is called relative paths, make sure to read up on those to understand how they work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a typo. The following relative path should work:

```
require(`../../data/${userId}/infos.json`)
```